# settings are not opening

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, gnome, lubuntu, sudo

I am a regular user of Ubuntu. I recently moved on from Ubuntu 18.04 for 20.04 LTS, but after the upgrade, the settings are not opening. Besides the settings, the display settings and the change background option are also not working.

I also tried

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

[image]

Comment: Your OS is unclear; as you've tagged both Lubuntu & GNOME.  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS was the *final* release that used the LXDE desktop, thus upgrades to later releases were **not supported** due to documented breakage with the change in desktop. A re-install was required on Lubuntu 18.04 LTS to effect an upgrade (ie. you need to install a later release). Also please provide a text version instead of a picture of text, it's hard to read the picture & I can't copy & explore your package issues - but please clarify your tags as Lubuntu 18.04 upgraded to 20.04 is *unsupported*.

Comment: https://lubuntu.me/focal-2-released/  "*Note, due to the extensive changes required for the shift in desktop environments, the Lubuntu team does not support upgrading from 18.04 or below to any greater release. Doing so will result in a broken system. If you are on 18.04 or below and would like to upgrade, please do a fresh install.*"